# How do I initialize an array of generic objects?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I'm creating a program that simulates an N-ary tree, but I got stuck when I started testing the node class because of a casting error.

**My code:**

```
public class NaryTreeNode<T> {
    
    private T data;
    int numChildren;
    NaryTreeNode<T>[] children;
    
    public NaryTreeNode (T data) {
        this.data = data;
        numChildren = 0;
        children = null;
    }
    
    public void addChild (NaryTreeNode<T> node) {
        if (children == null) {
            children = (NaryTreeNode<T>[]) (new Object[3]);
        }
        if (numChildren == children.length) {
            expandCapacity();
        }
        children[numChildren] = node;
        numChildren++;
    }
    
    public void expandCapacity() {
        NaryTreeNode<T>[] larger = (NaryTreeNode<T>[]) (new Object [numChildren + 3]);
        for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
            larger[i] = children[i];
        }
        children = larger;
    }
    
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        NaryTreeNode<String> node = new NaryTreeNode<String> ("a");
        NaryTreeNode<String> temp = new NaryTreeNode<String> ("b");
        node.addChild (temp);
    }
}
```

**The error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [LNaryTreeNode; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [LNaryTreeNode; is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at NaryTreeNode.addChild(NaryTreeNode.java:15)
    at NaryTreeNode.main(NaryTreeNode.java:35)
```

I've tried using `new NaryTreeNode<T>[3]` but it didn't work either, so I don't know how else to initialize the array.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What line is line 15?

Comment: `children = (NaryTreeNode<T>[]) Array.newInstance(NaryTreeNode.class, 3);`

Comment: This line does not appear in the code you presented. --- The fact that arrays are covariant and retained, while generics are invariant and erased makes an explosive mixture. If possible, I would suggest to not mix arrays and generics. However, if we need to keep the array, we could try using `new NaryTreeNode[3];` instead of `(NaryTreeNode<T>[]) (new Object[3]);`.

Comment: Note if you do this, you will have an array of type Object, not NaryTreeNode.  I'd suggest using `new NarryTreeNode[3]` instead.  I don't think `Object` is needed in this case (it's a common idiom in some other patterns involving generics).

Comment: @markspace [It will not run with `(List<String>[]) new Object[3]`](https://ideone.com/YORlgO).

Comment: You don't. Generics and arrays don't mix. If you want to do something like this, you're responsible for ensuring strict type correctness. Examine the source code of `ArrayList` for an example.

Comment: @sinclair: It's pointless to use `Array.newInstance()` with a hard-coded class. You might as well just use the regular array creation syntax.